# keras normalization methods

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization

Are the below two lines basically the same thing?

```
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
```

```
tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
```

I am trying to normalize(standardize in this case) the inputs for
fitting the neural network model using Tensorflow. After googling I found the two choices above. They seem to be the same thing but I'm not so sure. If they aren't the same, could anyone tell me the exact difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are technically the same thing. But you should use this one

```
tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
```

Because this one is not available anymore.

```
tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
```